# Why don't private jets use higher bypass turbofans?

Tags: turbofan, private-jets

Common private jet engines such as the [Williams FJ44](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Williams_FJ44) has a bypass ratio of just 2.8:1. Installation requirements aside. From an engineering perspective is there much to gain in efficiency by going to a higher bypass ratio on such small engines?

Comment: I guess private jets doesn't fly that much to justify the increased cost with fuel savings, especially in a segment so far away from "economy".

Comment: Lower bypass ratios are more efficient above 45000 ft where most bizjets are designed to cruise.